# Parameter documentation (info) not showing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, parameterinfo

I'm just wondering how it is that I can't see the *parameter documentation* on String.Format (C#) in *Visual Studio Code*.

Here's the example of Console.WriteLine (using Ctrl+Shift+Space):

[image: Working on Console.WriteLine]

Here's the example "not working" using String.Format:

[image: Not working on String.Format.]

I'm fairly new to *Visual Studio Code*. Perhaps I missed something. If someone can clarify this then that would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT: Visual Studio Code version: **1.15.1**. 
C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) version: **1.12.1**.

Comment: It seems that vscode is pulling from generated XML metadata if its available. In all other cases, it displays no description. I have seen already issue signed on vs-omnisharp github for this problem. So probably they will fix this soon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I also added an issue on the omnisharp-vscode GitHub for this.